# Apache cache control failure

Tags: apache

Please i need help so badly, i have turned on apache cache control on some files types especially font files using both expires module and header module (Not simultaneously). Every file specified caches except for font file, i have tried my best possible to fix it but no luck. Any solution to fix this?

Expires module method

```
##___________Cache control________________________________________##
# Declare fonts content-type
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

ExpiresActive on

ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 7200 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 7200 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 7200 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/svg+xml "access plus 7200 seconds"
Header append Cache-Control "public"
##________________________________________________________________________##
```

Header module method

```
##___________Cache control________________________________________##
<filesmatch "\.(ttf|jpg|svg|png|jpeg|ico|js)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</filesmatch>
##________________________________________________________________________##
```

Output

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
    <filesmatch "\.(ttf|jpg|svg|png|jpeg|ico|js)$">
          Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, 
          public"
   </filesmatch>
```

Try this:

```
    <FilesMatch regex> 
    </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Can you help with an example, because **"\.(ttf|jpg|svg|png|jpeg|ico|js)$"** is already a PCRE regex